# How to redirect in apache http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, redirect

It's still showing venue link and it doesn't redirect to directory-testing. is there any right way to redirecting in apache, on ubuntu.

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/venue  $1/directory-testing [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you actually enabled rewriting with:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

You can also check that your .htaccess file is actually being parsed.  You can just put a syntax error in it and see if it returns error 500.  If it doesn't, then you need to enable it in the `<directory>` section of your httpd.conf with:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: Yes, RewriteEngine on, I put AllowOverride All in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file in ubuntu, is it OK

Comment: Did you restart apache after making that change?  The easy way to check if it's being parsed is to put a syntax error in the .htaccess file then try going to your page, it should give error 500.

Comment: Yes, restarted and its parsing also, RewriteRule ^(.*)/venue/(.*)$  $1/directory-testing/$2 [R=301,L] is working, but we have to give testing.com/venue/ if I give testing.com/venue it wont work

Comment: Is it being overriden by another .htaccess file or another rewrite rule?  For example if you go to test/venue is there a test/.htaccess?  The rule itself is fine, I tested it on my server.

Comment: You are right sir, its conflicting, its working now :)